# Explanation of inductive bias of Candidate Elimination Algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, theory

The definition of inductive bias says that

> The inductive bias (also known as learning bias) of a learning algorithm is the set of assumptions that the learner uses to predict outputs given inputs that it has not encountered.

The inductive bias of Candidate elimination says that

> The target concept c is contained in the given hypothesis space H

My question is , how does this inductive bias help us to predict for next instance in given dataset?